# Powershell: How do I convert ADUser to IdentityReference?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl, directory

I am trying to set the owner on a folder and I keep running into problems. Here is my current script. I am trying to parse through all folders under a share and set the folder's owner to the corresponding ADUser based on the folder's name. Folder names are SAMAccountNames.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$path = Get-ChildItem F:\AppData\*\ | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
ForEach ($folder in $path) {
    $ACL = get-acl $folder
    $username = $folder.Name
    $userobject = Get-ADUser $username
    $ACL.SetOwner($userobject)
    Set-Acl $folder.FullName $ACL
    Write-Host $username
}
```

The error I get here though is:

> Cannot convert argument "Identity" with value (insert distinguished name here) for "SetOwner" to type System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount` like: `$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("<DOMAIN>", "<USERNAME>");
$acl.SetOwner($objUser)`

Comment: I think this works but a few folders get an error saying that "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

Comment: Nevermind that error seems to happen when the user id doesn't exist. Is there some way to handle errors?

Comment: Are there any other errors? Does `$userobject` actually have the user? Your logic is dependant on `$folder.Name`? Does that folder map back properly in those cases?

Comment: What are you going to do when the user does not exist?

Comment: Delete the folder if user doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes the $folder.Name should always match the SAMAccountName.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a single domain you could use the samaccountname of the user to create a `System.Security.Principal.NTAccount` object which would work with the `.SetOwner()` method.

```
$userobject = Get-ADUser $folder.Name
$ACL.SetOwner(New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("bagel", $userobject.samaccountname))
```

As you found it is possible that a user might not exist so you would need to account for that in order to mitigate future errors. One easy way is to check the result of `Get-Aduser`

```
$userobject = Get-ADUser $folder.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($userobject){
    # Found it. Do stuff
} else {
    # Could not find it. Do different stuff
}
```

**NOTE**. If getting the user fails for *any* reason this will trigger else. DC not available, user not found, permissions error etc.

If you want more control then you can try a `try`/`catch` looking for the specific errors etc.

```
try{
    Get-ADUser "cantpossiblyexist"
} catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]{
    "No. Mr. User not here"
}
```

Comment: Apparently it's not working at all though I was able to handle errors using the try catch method. The problem is I'm getting an error when adding the Set-Acl command - see my updated script. I get "The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object." - No idea what that means at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt for some of his help on this but the answer ended up being a bit different. Here is the final working product.

> IMPORTANT NOTE: The script must be run from another computer, ideally Windows 2012 or later, or else you will get an error saying "The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object."

```
$path = Get-ChildItem \\COMPUTERNAME\SHARENAME\* | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
ForEach ($folder in $path) {
    $ACL = (get-item $folder.FullName).GetAccessControl('Owner')
    $username = $folder.Name
    $userobject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("NTDOMAIN", $username)
    $AccessRule1 = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("CREATOR OWNER","FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","InheritOnly","Allow")
    $AccessRule2 = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("Domain Admins","FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","InheritOnly","Allow")
    $AccessRule3 = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($userobject,"FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","InheritOnly","Allow")

    try {
        $ACL.SetOwner($userobject)
        $ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule1)
        $ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule2)
        $ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule3)
        Set-Acl $folder.FullName $ACL
        Write-Host $username
    }
    catch {
        #Delete folder if user is not found.
        Remove-Item $folder -recurse -force
        Write-Host $username "CANNOT BE FOUND"
    }
}
```